# just_audio SocketException

Tags: socketexception, just-audio

When I am trying to open a source (url) without the internet on the device (flight mode on), I receive the next logs:

```dart
[   +1 ms] flutter: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'raw.githubusercontent.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)
[   +1 ms] flutter: 
           #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:35)
           #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1817:26)
           #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
           #3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:237:22)
           #4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:60:28)
           #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2438:24)
           #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2834:12)
           #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2839:12)
           #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2698:12)
           #9      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2575:48)
           #10     _proxyHandlerForUri.handler (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:3039:46)
           #11     _proxyHandlerForUri.handler (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:3038:23)
           #12     _ProxyHttpServer.start.<anonymous closure> (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1946:16)
           #13     _ProxyHttpServer.start<…>
```

try/catch doesn't help...

Any advice or idea?

---

UPDATE:

It take me some time to debug example app and compare with mine.
The issue comes cos I use headers with my `source`.

Here is piece of code from library, where dramattic change happened:

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> _setup(AudioPlayer player) async {
    await super._setup(player);
    if (uri.scheme == 'asset') {
      _overrideUri = await _loadAsset(uri.pathSegments.join('/'));
    } else if (uri.scheme != 'file' &&
        !kIsWeb &&
        (headers != null || player._userAgent != null)) {
      await player._proxy.ensureRunning();
      _overrideUri = player._proxy.addUriAudioSource(this);
    }
  }
```

we are interested in this particular line:

```dart
        (headers != null || player._userAgent != null)) {
```

I use headers, so in my app code goes futher, and then fails inside `_proxyHandlerForUri`, line 3039.

Comment: Have you tried all of the techniques listed in the README for catching errors? There's not only try/catch but also stream errors.

Comment: You could try listening to errors on the stream (see the `main.dart` example) or you could also take a look at the comments at the bottom of this issue on how to help the proxy recover from network disconnections: https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/594

Comment: @RyanHeise please take a look, I updated my question. I find out the place where the problem happens.

Comment: I think it's the same issue as https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/594 which I referred you to above. Did you try what was suggested in the comments over there?

Comment: @RyanHeise my case is different. Errors from `_server.listen((request) async {` are simply ignorred.

Comment: Your case will still have the same solution as 594. We don't want errors to be ignored for that issue either.